# Ring of a Spectral Space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abstract-algebra, gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras

It is said, as far as I can tell that an arbitrary spectral space, i.e. a space that is $T_0$, sober and quasi-compact whose collection of quasi-compact open sets forms a basis and is closed under finite intersections, must be $Spec(R)$ for some ring $R$. Is there a canonical (or any) way of reconstructing $R$ from its collection of prime ideals and the Zariski topology thereupon? What is the relationship of the functor $Spec:Rng\to SpectralSpaces$ and the functor (if it exists) going the other way $SpectralSpaces\to Rng$?

Thanks!

Comment: TThe set of prime ideals of _any_ field is the one-point space. 

Comment: Good point. This gives some intuitive evidence for the fact that Hochester's construction can give a ring that is an algebra over any field (since every space is in some sense a module over the one-point space).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [Prime ideal structure in commutative rings](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1995344) by Melvin Hochester where the theorem you mentioned is proved and functoriality discussed.

Comment: One question. Hochster's construction is believable, but rather unpleasantly intricate. Is there  any simpler way to do this? Is there a nice way of describing the necessary ring? I don't see any in Hochster's paper..